# fill in a vector with intgers with respect to constraints

Tags: r, algorithm

I'm using r and 
I want to fill a 8 lenght dimension vector/table with integer numbers form 1 to 4 with respect to the conditions below:

```
vector [i]<= vector[i+1]
```

all integrs should be present

example:

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 may be a solution 

1 2 1 1 2 3 3 4 isn't a solution to my problem
```

I am wondering also if there is a way to list all solutions

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you have any ideas?

Comment: If all the numbers in your vector are between 1 to 4, `sort(vector)` will guarantee the outcome is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To get all solutions, reserve four slots for the numbers `1:4` (since every number must appear at least once), and consider all possible length-4 sequences of `1:4` to fill the remaining slots. Sorting and removing duplicates leaves you with 35 non-decreasing sequences:

```
# The sequences will be the rows of a matrix. First, the 'reserved' slots:
reserved = matrix(1:4, 256, 4, byrow=TRUE)
# Add all combinations of 1:4 to fill the remaining four slots:
result = cbind(reserved,
               unname(as.matrix(expand.grid(1:4, 1:4, 1:4, 1:4))) )

# Now simply sort and de-duplicate along rows:
result = t(apply(result, 1, sort))
result = unique(result)

> head(result)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    2    3    4
# [2,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    3    4
# [3,]    1    1    1    1    2    3    3    4
# [4,]    1    1    1    1    2    3    4    4
# [5,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    3    4
# [6,]    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    4
```